# Php Mysql Column Value Not In Comma Separated String

Tags: php, mysql

I have below database structure where column `ip_visto` is comma separated ip addresses. I need to have a query where current ip address not in ip_visto values  [image]

I have below query so far

```
  $current_ip=$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
  $ad_info = $db->fetchRow("SELECT * FROM my_TABLE WHERE status='Active' and id!=" . $me_info['id'] ");
```

how can I pass `$current_ip not in ip_visto value in above query`

Comment: `WHERE !FIND_IN_SET($current_ip, ip_visto)`. Maybe excess space between comma and IP in `ip_visto` needs either `$current_ip=" ".$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];` or `WHERE !FIND_IN_SET($current_ip, REPLACE(ip_visto, ' ', '')`.

Answer (score 0):

First of All I want to say that your approach is not good to do this. You should save these IP Addresses in a separate table instead of saving them comma separated values.

Now, According to your current approach, I can see that there is a comma exist on each of the ip_visto values. So it means we can write a query for this purpose.

> $ad_info = $db->fetchRow("SELECT * FROM my_TABLE WHERE status='Active'
> and id!=" . $me_info['id'] AND ip_visto NOT LIKE '%,
> ".$current_ip.",%'");

The reason why I am adding a comma after % sign is that, If the current_ip=**1.2.3.4** then it will also matches with the ip **111.2.3.4**. So this is the reason I am adding a comma before the ip address because you are saving the ip address with a comma separated values.

Answer (score -1):

You can use [FIND_IN_SET](https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-find_in_set/) and [TRIM](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_trim.asp) leading/trailing comma separated

```php
$ip = 'YOUR IP HERE';

$q = "SELECT * FROM table_name 
   WHERE 
      status = 'Active' 
   AND 
      id != " . $me_info['id'] . " 
   AND
      NOT FIND_IN_SET('" . $ip . "', TRIM(BOTH ',' FROM ip_visto))";
```

Comment: See about sql injection and the importance of prepared and bound queries

Answer (score -3):

In your case, you need to use "NOT LIKE"

```
"SELECT * FROM my_TABLE WHERE status='Active' AND id!=". $me_info['id']" AND ip_visto NOT LIKE '%".$current_ip.",%'
```

Comment: Will give excess incorrect matches. For example, `1.2.3.4` will be found if `111.2.3.4` is present in IPs list.